# Coloring DiscretePlot3D according to min

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, discrete

I have two discrete functions, which I'll greatly simplify for this question:

```
RedFnc[i_, j_] := 1 + i + j;
BlueFnc[i_, j_] := 1 + (1 - i) + (1 - j);
```

I am interested in plotting the min:

```
MinFnc[i_, j_] := Min[RedFnc[i, j], BlueFnc[i, j]];
DiscretePlot3D[ 
 MinFnc[i, j], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1},
 ExtentSize -> Full]
```

---

[image: Discrete]

---

What I want to do is color the square-top Red if it is the RedFnc that determines the min, and Blue if it is the BlueFnc that determines the min. So the box in the front-left corner, over `{0,0,0}`, would have a Red top because $1 < 3$.

I cannot see how to accomplish this. So I need to color the tops of the cells according to a
certain pattern determined by the min.
It would be easier if I wanted to color according to the max, as
then I could just `Show[]` both and the higher one would be visible.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

---

*Postscript*. Here's what I produced with the help of MichaelE2 and kglr:

---

[image: BGR]

          

<sup>(Green: ties between Blue & Red functions.)</sup>

---

Comment: Thanks to both @MichaelE2 and @ kglr with functionally equivalent answers. Had to chose one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DiscretePlot3D[MinFnc[i, j], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}, 
 ExtentSize -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[RedFnc[#, #2] < BlueFnc[#, #2], Red, Blue] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

With `ColorFunction -> (If[RedFnc[#, #2] <= BlueFnc[#, #2], Red, Blue] &)` we get

[image]

Comment: Nice! May I ask what does `ColorFunctionScaling->False` do?

Comment: @Joseph, with default setting `ColorFunctionScaling->True` the arguments to the color function are scaled:  _"Scaling is done so as to make the minimum and maximum values of all variables lie between 0 and 1. "_  With `ColorFunctionScaling->False`  _"original unscaled values are fed to the color function."_

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this?

```
MinFnc[i_, j_] := Min[RedFnc[i, j], BlueFnc[i, j]];
DiscretePlot3D[MinFnc[i, j], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}, ExtentSize -> Full,
  ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{i, j, z}, If[z == RedFnc[i, j], Red, Blue]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

It reevaluates `RedFnc[i, j]`, which is just a minor irritation unless `RedFnc` is very slow.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize `ColorFunction` was that versatile.